# cannot find Chrome binary error (selenium) in java program deployed to heroku

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, heroku, binary

I've recently deployed my Java app to heroku. It's using selenium ChromeDriver, so i've installed these [buildpacks (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uZub.png). I'm getting this error while trying to init the chromedriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chromedriver");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
```

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

I know that my app can't find GoogleChrome browser installed and that causes an error. I've searched the internet and what I've found is setting config vars to **/app/.apt/usr/google/chrome/google-chrome** and i did [it (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU6K7.png).

I've also found guys advising to make a configuration, but all the code was written on Python and i'm new to such things, so i'm stuck.

I'm also sharing my [project tree screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6jKr.png) tree and my  [maven dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUzBl.png).

Pls, help me

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct chromedriver for your SO?

Comment: @RobertoPegoraro how can i check it?

Comment: Download again the correct webdriver: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.40/